# Князь рязанский или князь Рязанский?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная, ономастика, порядок-слов

Аналогичные случаи:

- Презрев все обещания, **тверской князь** Михаил отправился к новому хану.
- Благоверный великий **князь московский** Димитрий родился в 1350 году.
- Другим беспокойным соседом **московского князя** был Олег, **князь Рязанский**.

### Примеры из интернета. Не зависит ли правописание большой буквы от порядка слов?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Грамота.ру пишет:

> § 101. Пишутся с прописной буквы прилагательные, образованные от собственных географических названий:
>
> ...
>
> б) если они входят в состав сложных индивидуальных названий людей в
> качестве их прозвищ, например: Димитрий Донской, Александр Невский,
> Петр Амьенский;

Оле́г Ива́нович Ряза́нский — здесь "рязанский" действительно вошло в состав прозвища князя. Хотя разанских князей было много, в остальных случаях "рязанский" будет писаться со строчной буквы. От порядка слов это не зависит.